# Django Restframework error: getting Attribute error and Value error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-extensions

I'm getting the following errors while running my Django 1.11 project with djangorestframework and djangorestframework-extensions:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [profile] in 'RackToSystem object'
Exception while resolving variable 'profile' in template 'customers/rack-detail.template.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 882, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
TypeError: 'RackToSystem' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 890, in _resolve_lookup
    current = getattr(current, bit)
AttributeError: 'RackToSystem' object has no attribute 'profile'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 896, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'profile'
```

Here is my serializers.py code:

```
class RackToSystemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rack_system = serializers.SerializerMethodField('add_sys_attrs')

    def add_sys_attrs(self, racktosystem):
        try:
            r = racktosystem.system.pk
        except Exception as nfe:
            print('System entry NOT FOUND! Check the DB for racktosystem entries that are orphaned.')
            print(nfe)
            return {}

        system  = {
            'serial':       racktosystem.system.serial.number,
            'status':       racktosystem.system.sys_status,
            'connections':  racktosystem.system.reconcile_net_connections(),
            'position':     racktosystem.rack_position,
            'reports_path': racktosystem.system.reports_path,
            'device_type':  'server',
            'hw_violations':[],
        }

        try:
            profiles_to_systems  = ProfileToSystem.objects.filter(system__pk = r).select_related()

            for record in profiles_to_systems:
                results = record.validate()

                if results:
                    system['hw_violations'].append(results)
        except Exception as E:
            pass

        try:
            system['address'] = racktosystem.system.discovery_set.all().order_by('-created').first().address
        except Exception as e:
            # log_it('Unable to determine IP address for serial "%s". It is probably a new system. Error was: %s' % (system['serial'],e))
            system['address'] = 'Unknown'

        return(system)

    class Meta:
        model  = RackToSystem
        fields = ('rack','rack_system')
```

Here is my model in models.py:

```
class RackToSystem (models.Model):
    rack          = models.ForeignKey(Rack, db_column="rack_id")
    system        = models.ForeignKey(System, db_column="system_id", unique=True)
    rack_position = models.IntegerField(db_column="rack_position")
    updated       = models.DateTimeField(db_column="updated", auto_now=True, null=True)
    created       = models.DateTimeField(db_column="created", auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table            = "customer_rack_to_system"        
        verbose_name        = "Rack-to-System"
        verbose_name_plural = "Racks-to-Systems"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s [%s]" % (self.system, self.rack.name)
```

We recently migrated to Django 1.11 from 1.7.11 and upgraded to drf-extensions 0.5.0. Any help done to resolve will be greatly appreciated. This runs fine in Django 1.7.11 and djangorestframework-extensions 0.0.3 but not with drf-extensions. Let me know if you need any other details.

Comment: The error mention that RackToSystem has no attribute profile, where is profile?.

Comment: you are trying to convert str to int